# Using FontAwesome with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php, font-awesome

I've pulled fontAwesome into my codeIgniter project using composer and now I want to get the path to the font-awesome.css file and put it in my head but I can't work out how to do it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: @shomz it's myproject/vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css

Comment: So why can't you include it like that?

Answer (score 1):

## Base-Href

```
<head>
  <base href="<?php echo base_url();?>" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.css" />
<head>
```

## CDN

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

If relative paths aren't working, try `base_url`, e.g.:

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>path/to/css" />`